# Bernoulli in theano

Tags: theano

I have a question about Bernoulli mask.

As far as I understand the mask should be depending on the rate (probability) p. ( e.g. if p= 0.5 and the mask is an array A with size=2, then the mask should be something like:  [0,1] or [1,0]). 
The most of theano codes use bernoulli like :

rs = np.random.RandomState(1234)

rng = theano.tensor.shared_randomstreams.RandomStreams(rs.randint(999999))

mask = rng.binomial(n=1, p=(0.5), size=A.shape)

but when I test this I find out that the mask could also be [0,0] or [1,1], which seems for me to be not logic. Because I want to randomly set exactly the half of the array to zeros. 
Is there maybe a bug? or maybe there is an alternative that theano provides for that purpose. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`rng.binomial(n=1, p=0.5, shape=A.shape)` will sample from a Bernoulli distribution independently for each element of the result tensor with shape `A.shape`. Because each sample is independent each element of the result tensor will be zero with probability 0.5 and 1 with probability 0.5. Consequently, if the result tensor should have shape `(2, )` (i.e. a vector of length 2), there are four possible outcomes and each will be obtained with probability 0.25:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
```

It's not clear what your use-case is but if it is for a denoising autoencoder for example, this is the usual approach; sometimes you drop more features than at other times. Dropping all features is rather extreme but this is an unlikely outcome when the size of the result tensor is much larger than 2.

If you really need to mask exactly half the elements then you might be able to use [`theano.tensor.raw_random.shuffle_row_elements`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/raw_random.html). I've not tried this but the idea would be to symbolically shuffle a list of indexes using `shuffle_row_elements`, select the first half of the resulting list, then use `set_subtensor` to mask just those elements in the original tensors at the selected indexes.

Comment: thank you for responding my question! I'm actually using it for the dropout approach in neural networks.  So it would be 'rng.binomial' the right one since in all papers they mentioned that the mask should have a bernoulli distribution

Comment: I think it also normal to use independent Bernoulli samples in dropout so the number of inputs that are dropped can change and may mean every input is dropped sometimes (depending on the size of the input).